# Python 3.3.0 Error

Tags: python

Tried my first programm with Python 3.3.0

```
print ("cookies")
x= input ("enter your name")
print ("good day to you sir ") + x
```

when i want to start my programm with F5 it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/cookies.py", line 3, in <module>
    print ("good day to you sir ") + input
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
print ("good day to you sir ") + x
```

`print` is a function in Python 3, so the parentheses belong to the function. The `print` function itself has a return value of `None` so what you essentially do is `None + x`, which raises exactly the error you get.

What you want to do instead is to concat the two strings directly, within the parentheses:

```
print("good day to you sir " + x)
```

Also your exception is actually a bit different, there you still have `print(..) + input` (I guess this was an older version of your code?) Note that `input` is a reference to the function that gets the data from the user, so you actually try to add `None` and a function reference.

Answer (score 1):

correct way to print value is `print ("hello", input)` or `print ("hello" + input)`

Answer (score 0):

All text and variables to be printed have to be within the brackets of a print function.

so instead of:

```
print("good day to you sir ") + x
```

it would be:

```
print("good day to you sir " + x)
```

or, you could also use a comma instead of a plus sign to automatically give a space:

```
print("good day to you sir", x)
```

All other parts of the code are fine.